# Visual Studio 2010 File->New->Project Grayed Out

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I created a solution of Win32 Project.

Then I clicked on File->New->Project and created a new Win32 Project, but added the project to the current solution, just so I could see both projects in the Solution Explorer. (Because Visual Studio can only display one solution at once, as I am told).

Now I am trying to create a third project to the solution, but when I go to File->New->Project, this option is totally grayed out.

What happened here? And how do I solve it? What I want is to be able to have many projects in the Solution Explorer, and I tried to do so by adding the projects to current solution.

Comment: Weird.  I just tried it and I didn't see the option to add to the existing solution at all on the third project.  Either way, it's probably easier (and works ad infinitum) if you just right click on the solution in the solution explorer, go to Add, and click on new project (or existing project).

Comment: There's no such add option. The options I get from right clicking are: Build Solution, Rebuild Solution, Clean Solution, Batch Build..., Calculate Code Metrics, Project Dependencies..., Project Build Order..., Set As StartUp Project (grayed out), Add Solution to Source Control..., Paste (grayed out), Rename, Open Folder in Windows Explorer, and Properties..     When I click on an individual Project, I see the Add Option, but it doesn't have a New Project Option (It only has New Item, Existing Item, New Filter, Class..., Resource...)

Answer (score 12):

I was in Debugging Mode (ie running my program). Therefore, New Project was grayed out. To fix the issue, simply exit debugging mode (Shift + F5)